# Removing all partial transparency in GIMP

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have an image that has transparent edges around a main drawing, the edges are a semi-transparent black.

**Is there any way to remove all partial transparency from the image instead of removing all of it?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to remove the transparency of the partially transparent pixels, use *Layer>Transparency>Threshold alpha*. Depending on the threshold this will either make the edge pixels totally transparent or totally opaque.

But these semi-transparent pixels are there to make the edges appear smooth, you normally want to keep them. If you need to remove them the problem may be elsewhere in your workflow.

Comment: +1 I got an image with outer transparency and semi-transparent border, but some of the colors inside were only 95% opaque by accident. I selected the inside of the image, making sure to keep some distance from the border (was easy in my case), then use your technique to ensure everything inside the image was fully opaque, while not changing the semi-transparency of the border.

Comment: @Zefiro For this I would have added a layer mask (transferring the alpha channel to it) and then using Levels or Curves  on the mask to transform the 95% to 100%. Then no selection is even necessary, since only the near-opaque pixels will see a significant change.